# Apt-get update is failing and I can't figure out the source of it

Tags: ubuntu, apt-get

For some reason when I try to do a `sudo apt-get update` it checks all the source lists and ends with this

```
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'contrib/source/Sources' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
```

Problem is I can't find that line in `sources.list` or in the `sources.list.d` directory. Can someone help me figure out where this might be coming from?

Answer (score 0):

First of all source.list can be found in `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

It looks like you are missing the basic repository sources. This should be:

```
deb http://ru.archive.com/ubuntu/ maverick main restricted
deb-src http://ru.archive.com/ubuntu/ maverick main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick main-security restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick main-security restricted
```

What Ubuntu version are you running?